# forming and using Regular expressions in R

Tags: regex, r

Som I am new to R. I was learning this concept of forming regular expressions.

i.e. something like this `"(\\2.\\3)"`. What are these? I mean, what do these numbers and notation represents? Can anyone explain in a very layman language what does this mean? Or something like this, `(\2.\4)(\2.\4)`, what does it mean? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6):

They are called [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) which recall what was matched by a capturing group. A [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) can be created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parenthesis `( )`. A backreference is specified as a backslash (`\`) in R, two backslashes (`\\`); followed by a digit **indicating the number of the group** to be recalled.

Below is an example replacing using backreferences to recall what was matched by capturing group `#2` and `#3` ...

```
x <- 'foo bar baz quz'
sub('(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+)', '(\\2.\\3)', x)
# [1] "(bar.baz)"
```

**Note:** The opening and closing parenthesis in the replacement along with the dot are literal characters.