# Split a string every 5 characters

Tags: r, string, split

Suppose I have a long string:

```
"XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW"
```

How do I split this to get every 5  characters followed by a space?

```
"XOVEW VJIEW NIGOI WENVO IWEWV WEW"
```

Note that the last one is shorter.

I can do a loop where I constantly count and build a new string character by character but surely there must be something better no?

Comment: check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chopping a string into a vector of fixed width character elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247045/chopping-a-string-into-a-vector-of-fixed-width-character-elements)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
gsub("(.{5})", "\\1 ", "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW")
# [1] "XOVEW VJIEW NIGOI WENVO IWEWV WEW"
```

Comment: @flodel, can you help explain "\\1 "? I've figured everything else out but that stumbles me

Comment: @user1357015 I think hwnd does a nice job explaining this idea here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26495062/1000343

Comment: this is awesome, and super fast :)

Comment: What would be the way to reverse this? For example, how would you do this starting from the right, and going to left? Also, instead of splitting by 5, lets say i want the first 8 characters and the last 6 characters separated, so it would look like:  ` "XOVEWVJI EWNIGOIWENVOIW EWVWEW" `

Comment: This answer is good, but with text that is a multiple of 5 characters long, it will put an extra space at the end.  To make it match 5 characters only with at least one character after it, you would want to use a positive lookahead perl regular expression: `gsub("(.{5})(?=.)", "\\1 ", "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWV", perl = TRUE)` giving `# [1] "XOVEW VJIEW NIGOI WENVO IWEWV"`.

Answer (score 16):

Using `sapply`

```
> string <- "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW"
> sapply(seq(from=1, to=nchar(string), by=5), function(i) substr(string, i, i+4))
[1] "XOVEW" "VJIEW" "NIGOI" "WENVO" "IWEWV" "WEW"
```

Answer (score 10):

No *apply `stringi` solution:

```
x <- "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW"
stri_sub(x, seq(1, stri_length(x),by=5), length=5)
[1] "XOVEW" "VJIEW" "NIGOI" "WENVO" "IWEWV" "WEW"
```

This extracts substrings just like in @Jilber answer, but `stri_sub` function is vectorized se we don't need to use *apply here.

Answer (score 9):

You can try something like the following:

```
s <- "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW" # Original string
l <- seq(from=5, to=nchar(s), by=5) # Calculate the location where to chop

# Add sentinels 0 (beginning of string) and nchar(s) (end of string)
# and take substrings. (Thanks to @flodel for the condense expression)
mapply(substr, list(s), c(0, l) + 1, c(l, nchar(s)))
```

Output:

```
[1] "XOVEW" "VJIEW" "NIGOI" "WENVO" "IWEWV" "WEW"
```

Now you can `paste` the resulting vector (with `collapse=' '`) to obtain a single string with spaces.

Comment: should be pasted and collapsed methinks

Comment: This looks great, I can paste and collapse from here. But would you mind giving some insight onto how that mapply works? Thanks!

Comment: @user1357015 Added some comments.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a sub-string without a loop.  `substring` is the vectorized `substr`

```
x <- "XOVEWVJIEWNIGOIWENVOIWEWVWEW"
n <- seq(1, nc <- nchar(x), by = 5) 
paste(substring(x, n, c(n[-1]-1, nc)), collapse = " ")
# [1] "XOVEW VJIEW NIGOI WENVO IWEWV WEW"
```