# regex. Get character preciding by n characters

Tags: regex, r

I need to change a string like that

> blah blah blah, trulala, trampam pam, tararam

to

> blah blah blah,\ntrulala, trampam\npam,tararam

I tried to use regex "(?:.){10}([[:blank:]])" with R's gsub function like that

```
gsub("(?:.){10}([[:blank:]])", "\n", "blah blah blah, trulala, trampam pam, tararam")
```

, but got

> blah \ntrulal\npam, tararam

Is there any way one can do that?

Comment: You need to use backreferences in the replacement string to copy the capture groups.

Comment: Also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26494995/forming-and-using-regular-expressions-in-r/26495062#26495062

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a backreference to copy the capture group into the replacement.

```
gsub("(.{10})[[:blank:]]", "\\1\n", "blah blah blah, trulala, trampam pam, tararam")
```

You need to put the entire `.{10}` expression inside the first group, and it should be a capturing group. You don't need a capture group around `[[:blank:]]`, since that's being replaced, not copied.